# Creating Smooth and Clean Graphics

Tags: gimp, images, image-quality

I'm interested in creating graphics on a computer rather than drawing them out.

I draw out things by hand, copy them onto the computer, and then trace over them with tools in a program called Gimp.

The trouble is that the lines always end up looking dirty or pixelated.

I did some research and found that I vector graphics may help the images scale better. But even before I scale them, they look really pixelated no matter what shapes or brush sizes/types I use.

Am I using the wrong tool/technique? Would it be better to try and get one of those pads that you draw on that automatically renders your drawing to a computer screen?

I tried to narrow the question down, but I'm really new to computer graphics and I'm not sure how to pinpoint what the problem is.

Comment: Gimp is *not* a vector graphics tool. If you are using Gimp, you are not creating vector graphics. Have you tried something like Inkscape, Sketch, or Adobe Illustrator?

Comment: @Scott Thanks. I haven't tried those. I'll try Inkscape because it looks like it works on Linux. Is it only possible to get clean lines with vector graphics?

Comment: Well "clean lines" is a somewhat relative term. If you create art "at size" (meaning at 100%) in a raster editor things should be fine. But scaling raster images (pixels) is always inferior when compared to scaling vector images (mathematical plots).

Comment: Depends how you trace them. The Path tool in Gimp is vector graphics and you can get squeaky clean lines with it (`Edit>Stroke path` espcially in `Line` mode). If you just need the lines it will be better done with Inkscape, but if the lines are only a beginning (painting, effects applied later) you can possibly do everything in Gimp.